# ngClipboard : expression value not getting replaced on copy

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a ***copy to clipboard*** button on an error information tab which copies the error info. The error information is ***dynamically generated*** depending on which information is required. I have the error information generated in the form of an expression.

When I try to link the expression to **data-clipboard-target** the value is only stored statically, that is when close the first tab and open another one and click on copy it still reflects the previously copied information.

```
 <div style="white-space:pre-wrap;" id="toCopy"> 
     {{data[$index].text_mex}}
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngclipboard ngclipboard-succes ="onSuccess(e);" ng-clipboard-error="onError(e);" data-clipboard-target="#toCopy">Copy to Clipboard</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```

{{data[$index].text_mex}} is the expression that is dynamically evaluated.

References:  [ngClipboard](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/), [ngClipboard Source](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/ngclipboard/blob/master/dist/ngclipboard.js)

PS: I have added ngclipboard as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, **$index** variable in Angular provides an **offset** for the ids and thus the elements are linked dynamically. Hope this is helpful for someone else :)

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap;" id="toCopy{{$index}}"> 
     {{data[$index].text_mex}}
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngclipboard ngclipboard-succes ="onSuccess(e);" ng-clipboard-error="onError(e);" data-clipboard-target="#toCopy{{$index}}">Copy to Clipboard</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```